# Use a derived class in fluent nHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables which share common fields.  Rather than re-map all of these I would like to have a base class with the common fields.  For POCO this is simple:

```
class Base
{
   public string commonField {get;set;}
}
class Derived : Base
{
   public string specificField {get;set;}
}
class OtherDerived : Base
{
   public string specificOtherField {get;set;}
}
```

Note that there is no such thing as a table for "base".  It just holds lots of common fields shared among several tables.  Yes, I know this is not well normalized, but it's what I have to work with.

My question is - is there a way to implement this in fluent nHibernate without having to duplicate the code that maps those common properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inherit from `ClassMap` to do this.  I would do something like the following:

```
public class BaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Base
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.commonField, "COMMON_FIELD");
    }
}

public class DerivedMap : BaseMap<Derived>
{
    public DerivedMap()
    {
        Table("DERIVED_TABLE");
        Polymorphism.Explicit();  //You may want to use this in your case.
        Map(x => x.DerivedField, "DERIVED_FIELD");
    }
}
```

Notice the `Polymorphism.Explicit();` above.  In your case I think you are going to want this.

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-class

Comment: Thank you. This is working, without needing the PolyMorphism yet. I also saw it here: http://geekswithblogs.net/nharrison/archive/2010/07/09/inheriting-a-class-map-in-fluent-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: In my case the missing part was the Polymorphism, thanks for pointing that out!! The situation where I needed is was as follows: have a basemap with common fields id setting/mappings, then have a derivedmap which has the HasMany()'s, References(), etc set. I query from the basemap for gridview like listings, and querying the derivedmap for a specific ID with all the related informations.