# Fluent mapping base class - Tried to add property when already added

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a base class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a series of other entities that inherit from this:

```
public class User : MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping for `User` would be:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);

        Map(x => x.UpdatedOn);
    }
}
```

I then have other entities, mapped the same way.
My problem is I get the following error:

> Tried to add property 'UpdatedOn' when already added.

I guess this is because I map the `UpdatedOn` column in every entity?
Each of my tables has this UpdatedOn column, so how should I be mapping it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use a derived class in fluent nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154583/use-a-derived-class-in-fluent-nhibernate/12160356#12160356)

This question should help you out.  You can basically use a base fluent nhibernate mapping class to map your `UpdatedOn` column and derive all of your other mapping classes from that base class.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar kind of situation. I did like this..it works...
I was supposed to exposes entities as Interface..

```
public interface IEntity 
{              
    DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }               
    DateTime UpdationDate { get; set; }             
}

public interface IUser  : IEntity
{
    DateTime UserName { get; set; }
    DateTime Password { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployee : IEntity
{
    DateTime Name { get; set; }
    DateTime Key { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{               
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime UpdationDate { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity, IUser
{
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }    
}

public class Employee : Entity, IEmployee
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Key { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);

        Map(x => x.CreationDate);
        Map(x => x.UpdationDate);
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Key);

        Map(x => x.UpdationDate);
        Map(x => x.CreationDate);
    }
}
```